# to reduce http requests which thing should be taken first?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, yslow

I'm working on a website optimization where I need to improve the performance now so I used yslow and it suggested below things to improve to reduce http request.

Which problem should be solved first to improve performance suggested by yslow? or anyone can be taken because it will just save http request?

> This page has 20 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
>   This page has 20 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
>   This page has 20 external background images. Try combining them with CSS sprites.

Answer (score 2):

The external background images to sprites suggestion will probably be the most significant, since that's likely to be more data. Combining the JS / CSS files should both be roughly similar.
I'd suggest using all 3 suggestions, though.

All 3 suggestions will reduce the HTTP requests by the same amount, though.

Comment: _ I will do all 3. but just asked to know which will give max boost or all are same.

Comment: It depends on the size of your files. That can be reduced quite a bit with sprites, for example.

Comment: ok so combining js and css files will save less bytes compare to images

Comment: Most likely, yes. JS / CSS files are plain text, where barely any data can be saved by combining them (Although it does still reduce the amount of requests) Combining images into a sprite, however, can get quite lucrative.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest having a look at [minification](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#minify), as Chris suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend doing all three suggestions. As for which one to do first, it doesn't really matter, since it looks like each of them would be turning 20 requests into 1.

From [the yslow documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http) (emphasis mine):

> 80% of the end-user response time is spent on the front-end. Most of this time is tied up in downloading all the components in the page: images, stylesheets, scripts, Flash, etc. **Reducing the number of components in turn reduces the number of HTTP requests required to render the page. This is the key to faster pages.**

Now, if you're doing [minification](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#minify) at the same time, then you can make the gains in your Javascript and CSS relative to the size of the content.  For this reason, I'd recommend to start with either of these two, and do minification alongside file combining.

> When code is minified all comments are removed, as well as unneeded white space characters (space, newline, and tab). In the case of JavaScript, this improves response time performance because the size of the downloaded file is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried "lazy load".

+

Try to shrink CSS and JavaScrip files (combining them into one file.)

Comment: shrinking is minification, and combining into one file is what the question is about (just which type of combining should take priority) - your answer makes it look like they are the same thing.

Comment: it seems i did not get your point yet ..

what i want to tell is the best optimization for your site is 

Combination, Minify, Data URIs and gzip compression.

Comment: My comment was referring to the phrasing "Try to shrink CSS and JavaScrip files (combining them into one file.)"  This reads like "combining them into one file" is just another way of saying "shrink CSS/JS" - ie: that they are the same thing. I'd suggest rephrasing it to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't matter, the aim is to reduce the number of individual requests.